# Find all polynomials $A \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ which stabilise the set of prime numbers

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

Let be $\mathcal{P}$ the set of prime numbers.

I would like to determine the set of polynomials $A \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $A(\mathcal{P}) = \mathcal{P}$.

What I have tried so far:

- I proved that, if $\forall p \in \mathcal{P}, A(p) = p$, then: $A = X$.
- Then, if $A \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, $A(p) \equiv A(0) \pmod{p}$ so that, if $A(0) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then, by the previous statement: $A = X$. Otherwise, I don't see how to proceed whenever $p \nmid A(0)$
- If $A \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$, I think I could get back into $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by multiplying by the PPCM of all denominators and reuse my previous results.
- If $A \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, I have no idea how to proceed because all prime numbers have non-unique factorization using irrationals and inverses.
- If $A$ is injective, then it must be increasing and we must have $A(2) > A(1) > A(0)$ and $A(2) \geq 2$, at the same time, $A$ must be surjective for prime numbers, so that there must be $x \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $A(x) = 2$, if $A(2) > 2$, then $x < 2$, that's impossible. Then: $x = 2$ and $A(2) = 2$, I guess that we could iterate this idea to get that $A = X$ once again. Now, I know that if $A \neq X$, then $A$ is not injective.
- I tried to look at roots of such polynomial, but I'm not even sure how to use this in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: If deg A > 1, then as x goes to infinity, the derivative of A becomes and stays positive or negative. So in particular A becomes monotonic, so it becomes injective on (N, infty) for some large N. Maybe you can extend the argument in your fifth bullet point? (Which is definitely missing some details as it is.)

Comment: @AreaMan I tried your hint, and reached a step where I can only prove that, if we denote $p_k$ the $k$-th prime number, for some large $N$: $A(p_N) = p_N$ or $A(p_N) = p_{N + 1}$, I'm not sure how to rule out the case where $A(p_N) = p_{N + 1}$ :/.

Comment: maybe it can't be done that way, I don't know. Can you think of any infinite subset of the natural numbers that is fixed by a polynomial other than X?

Comment: @AreaMan Odd/even numbers, I would say?

Comment: what polynomial?

Comment: @AreaMan $X^2$ fix even and odd numbers AFAIK.

Comment: but 2 isn't in the image, for example. Maybe I'm not understanding you?

Comment: @AreaMan Ah! You're right, I was only considering $A(S) \subset S$ rather than $A(S) = S$, I don't see also such a set, you're right.

Comment: me neither. So I'm not sure if there's something special about the primes here or not.

Comment: @AreaMan The current answer uses Dirichlet's theorem which is clearly a statement about prime numbers which seems to indicate there is something special about the primes.

Comment: True, but especially if you are looking for a more elementary proof, it seems natural to inquire about what can be shown when considering just an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $Q(x)$ is a polynomial sending prime numbers to prime numbers. Let $d$ denote the degree of $Q(x)$. Write $p_k$ for the $k$th prime number. We know $Q(p_j) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $1\le j \le d+1$, so by e.g. Lagrange interpolation, it follows that $Q(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Let $Q(x) = \tilde{Q}(x) / c$ for $\tilde{Q}(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $c\in \mathbb{Z}$ (where $c$ is relatively prime to at least one of the coefficients of $\tilde{Q}$).

Suppose $p$ is any prime large enough such that $Q(p)$ does not divide $c$. If $Q(p)\neq p$, then by Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions, we can find infinitely many primes $q$ such that $q\equiv p \pmod{Q(p)}$. For each such $q$, we have $$Q(q) \equiv Q(p) \equiv 0 \pmod{Q(p)} \implies Q(q) = Q(p)$$ so the value $Q(p)$ is attained infinitely often by $Q$, contradiction. Hence $Q(p) = p$ for all large enough primes $p$. We conclude $Q(x) = x$.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the "non-elementary" Dirichlet's theorem?